# Most popular Genre(s) for content creators (e.g. Youtubers, game designers, etc.)

Tags: electronic-music

For a school project I am creating a piece of software that uses algorithmic composition to compose a song independently based on certain parameters (key signature, tempo etc.). My tutor informed me that it may be naive to have the software compose various different genres with reasonable accuracy, therefore....

What would be the best one to three musical genres to focus on? Any opinions are welcome but ideally I'd want someone who is a content creator to reply.

P.S. None of my preferred tags were available so I was forced to settle with one that isn't really an accurate match.

Comment: I love it when people downvote without commenting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this chart](http://www.hypebot.com/hypebot/2015/01/nielson-study-reveals-rock-prevails-as-most-popular-genre-in-the-us-.html), you'll probably want to stick with Rock, R&B/Hip-Hop, Pop and Country, as those 4 make up the widest spread of popular music.  It really wouldn't make any sense to program something that few people would be interested in hearing, like Jazz or Classical.  Not that those genres aren't good, it's just that they make up a very slim portion of what's popular.